# Extracting end of String - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Say I have a string 12.13.14

How can I get the characters after the last dot. (in this case 14)?

There can be more than 2 characters.

Examples would be  
34.45.657
                   10.11.46256

So after the last dot could be any amount of characters.

I've messed around with .slice() but can't get anywhere.

Comment: ignore my deleted suggestion ... `split('.').pop()` is better though

Comment: @JaromandaX ok thanks, never heard of .pop() before

Comment: Arrays have `.shift()`/`.unshift()` to work the head and `.push()`/`.pop()` to work the tail ... `.split()` creates the array to work with

Comment: @JaromandaX: I've never heard it put that way before. That's wonderfully concise.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - you can tweet it with characters to spare :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bunch of options. One is `split` and `pop`:

```js
var str = "12.13.14";
var last = str.split('.').pop();
document.body.innerHTML = last;
```

Another is a regular expression

```js
var str = "12.13.14";
var match = /\.([^.]+)$/.exec(str);
var last = match && match[1];
document.body.innerHTML = last;
```

Or a rex and replace:

```js
var str = "12.13.14";
var last = str.replace(/^.*\.([^.]+)$/, "$1");
document.body.innerHTML = last;
```

Or `lastIndexOf` and `substring`, as [Ananth shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33936675/157247).

Comment: Only `lastIndexOf` is missing ;-)

Comment: Thanks!! Great answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = '34.45.657';
console.log(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in multiple ways:

**First way:**

```
var myString = '12.13.14';
var lastItem = myString.split('.').pop();
console.log(lastItem);
```

**Second Way:**

```
var myString = '12.13.14';
var lastItem = myString.slice(myString.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
console.log(lastItem);
```

**Third Way:**

```
var myString = '12.13.14';
var lastItem = myString.substring(myString.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
console.log(lastItem);
```

and so on ,...

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) which takes a delimiter.

You could split your string on dots and since split returns an array you could use [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to get the last result.

e.g.

```
'34.345.3456'.split('.').pop(); // 3456
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution to get your answer like this

```
var txt= document.getElementById("Text1").value;
var s1 = txt.lastIndexOf(".");
txt = txt.substring(0, s1);
```